# Empty documentation.json in Compodocs + Storybook + Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9, storybook, compodoc, angular-storybook

I started to use compodoc + storybook in a Angular 9 project.

Installed all the dependencies and Storybook is working fine, but for some reason the documentation.json generated by compodoc is empty, like this:

```
{
    "pipes": [],
    "interfaces": [],
    "injectables": [],
    "classes": [],
    "directives": [],
    "components": [],
    "modules": [],
    "miscellaneous": [],
    "routes": [],
    "coverage": {
        "count": 0,
        "status": "low",
        "files": []
    }
}
```

The command I'm using is:

```
compodoc -p .storybook/tsconfig.json -e json -d ./.storybook
```

And my tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "extends": "../src/tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "../src/test.ts",
    "../src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "../projects/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "../src/**/*",
    "../projects/**/*"
  ],
  "files": [
    "./typings.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Any ideas of what may be wrong?

Comment: Did you have any progress?

Comment: @Dekim Not yet. It seems to be a bug. Unfortunately. :( https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc/issues/951

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After switching from `-p tsconfig.app.json` to `-p tsconfig.json` it worked. We have both files, but I think compodoc does not understand that `tsconfig.app.json` extends the `tsconfig.json` file since both are written in JSON and there is no such thing as dependency.

[Source](https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc/issues/927#issuecomment-603690089)

Comment: Well, that did the trick. My command became: compodoc -p tsconfig.json -e json -d ./.storybook and now it works!

Comment: That did the trick for me too, thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `tsconfig.base.json` instead of `tsconfig.json`

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me, but this. Angular 10, newly created project.